# Can I upload iOS App to AppStore using Xcode 8.2, even if apple has release Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.3

Tags: swift3, xcode8.2, ios10.2, ios10.3, xcode8

As stated by apple in [Xcode 8.3 release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/DeveloperTools/RN-Xcode/Chapters/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001051-CH1-SW160)

**Xcode 8.3 no longer supports Swift 2.3**.

I have a lot of work before I migrate to Swift 3.0 And I want My app on AppStore soon before I migrate.

Keeping in mind that apple has recently relaease a new version Xcode 8.3 and iOS 10.3, will I be able to upload the iOS app to appstore using my older version of Xcode 8.2

*NOTE: I already have an active version x.x of my app on appstore. I need to upload a new version.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minimum Xcode version to upload to App store](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891165/minimum-xcode-version-to-upload-to-app-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41891165/minimum-xcode-version-to-upload-to-app-store) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39384272/can-i-submit-swift-2-2-app-with-xcode-7-3-when-ios-10-is-released), any version from Xcode 6.0 and over, regardless of which language (and language version) you use, will do.