# Can I build an app for iOS 10 on Mac Mini Late 2009

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, macos

Am new to iOS development please help me to understand.

I've got a Mac Mini Late 2009 Core 2 Duo. It's running EL Capitan, and as far as my knowledge concern it can not be updated to Sierra. Please correct me if am wrong.

If I can not update the OS, then can I build apps for iOS 8 & that app should also work on iOS 10. Because on EL Capital I can run only Xcode 7.3 as far as my knowledge concern.

But I guess apps which are already there in market targeted for iOS 7 or 8, at-least not all apps but 80% of them also run on iOS 9 or 10.

Please forgive me if asking the wrong question but please don't ban me.

Comment: Before this question gets closed - yes you can. But probably not later than that. I am not on Sierra myself and am running the latest SDK on El Capitan.

Comment: Xcode Version 8.2 (8C38) works with El Capitan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your question was answered here: [Minimum Xcode version to upload to App store (As on February 2016)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35285502/minimum-xcode-version-to-upload-to-app-store-as-on-february-2016)

Based on that, the summary is that it might or it might not work. Apple says:

> But it's important to understand that using an older SDK is a
>   temporary workaround, not a solution. Issues preventing your app from
>   using the latest SDK should be fixed as soon as possible. It will be
>   much easier to fix these issues while the older build system is still
>   supported.

And also guide you to verify if your Xcode configuration is accepted:

> To determine if an older Xcode configuration is currently accepted by
>   the App Store, you can choose "Archive" under the "Product" menu to
>   make an archived build, then use the Validate feature, to test if that
>   build meets minimum requirements for submission to the App Store.

More info about it here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1806/_index.html

I hope this helps :)